# Tomcat does not cache session for non-authenticated user

Tags: java, session, tomcat, caching

I'm using FORM based authentication with DataSourceRealm.  When user is logged in, the session correctly gets cached and I maintain the same sessionID as long as I remain logged in.

However, when user is not logged in, Tomcat is changing my session on every request.  I need the session to remain active even if the user is not logged in.

Is there a way to get Tomcat to cache a session of unauthenticated users?

***Edit:***

One notable detail that I just noticed is that it only happens on subdomains.  i.e. When I go to http://www.example.com/, I correctly get the same session ID on every request whether I'm authenticated or not.  However, if I go to http://subdomain.example.com/, unauthenticated users get a different sessionID for every request.

In my context.xml, I have:

```
<Context sessionCookiePath="/" sessionCookieDomain=".example.com">
  ...
  <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor" />
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator"/>
</Context>
```

Also, I've tried using:

```
changeSessionIdOnAuthentication="false"
```

without success.

Comment: Tomcat version?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 8.

Comment: Don't use `JDBCRealm`. Use `DataSourceRealm` instead.

Comment: Sessions are maintained independently of the user's authentication status. When a user authenticates, their session id will change, but the backing session object will stay the same. Can you give a little more information about your environment? Number of Tomcat instances, whether you are trying to use clustering, etc.?

Comment: I only have one tomcat instance. I am using the session ID to maintain user session data (shopping cart).  But if the ID changes every request, I lose my reference.  This only happens when the user has not authenticated.  If I authenticate, I keep the same session ID for every request.

Comment: Correction, I am using DataSourceRealm (not JDBCRealm)

Comment: I've edited my original question with more details.